# Entity object's virtual list is null, how do I initialise it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have two Entities `BlogPost` and `Tag`, and I want to be able to add/retrieve a list of `Tag`s associated with each `BlogPost`, but also a list of `BlogPost`s associated with each `Tag`.

In theory, this should be fine, as there will be a table `BlogPostTags` which will link them together by `BlogPostId` to `TagId`.

The problem I have is when I am trying to add `Tag`s to a new `BlogPost`, the `BlogPost.Tags` property is null.

How do I initialise the list, even to just an empty list, so that I can add the `Tag`s to it?

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
    public string BlogContent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere the tags are created like so:

```
Tag tag1 = context.Tags.Create();
tag1.TagName = "test1";
context.Tags.Add(tag1);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And then I want to be able to add them to a new `BlogPost`:

```
BlogPost post = context.BlogPosts.Create();
post.BlogTitle = "Test post";
post.BlogContent = "this is a test blog and as such lorem bacon.";
post.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
post.Tags.Add(tag1);
context.BlogPosts.Add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But `post.Tags` throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise the list in the constructor

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
    public string BlogContent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public BlogPost()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}
```

and the same for the other class

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        BlogPosts = new List<BlogPost>();
    }
}
```